# How to Change inputs of keyboard to touch controls in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game where i simply has to use a virtuel joystick instead of WASD. Everything i've done didn't work, i could really use some help.
My code for now is this:

```
private void Update()   
{
    Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.left);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.right);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.back);

}
```

However, i've also writtin this code:

```
float moveHorizontal = joystick.Horizontal;
    float moveVertical = joystick.Vertical;

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

    rb.AddForce(movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

I already have a joystick and i saw in a YT video that he uses joystick.Horizontal. I want the W key for example to be, if joystick goes up move forward or something like that. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

Your first code should work, but the amount of force you add is probably too small for you to see it move.

Try multiplying it by some value like: `rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward*50);`

---

Even if it works, you should know that it is not very optimized. For example, you should not get the Rigidbody in every update, try something like:

```
public float speed = 50f;

private Rigidbody rb;

void Awake() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.left * speed);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.right * speed);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * speed);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.back * speed);
}
```

---

Finally for those who are more familiar with Unity, I encourage you to use the  [New Input System](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gz0YcjXBJ3U).